# Nested While Loops in JavaScript how to solve

Tags: javascript

I was using a nested while loop, and ran into a problem, as the inner loop is only run once. To demonstrate I've made a bit of test code:

```js
let i = 1, j = 1;
while (i < 5) {
  console.log('outer', i);
  while (j < 4) {
    console.log('inner', j);
    j++;
  }
  i++;
}
```

Help me how to solve this problem, I have tried in every but the reuslt was the same

Comment: You're not resetting `j` back to 1 inside the outer while loop. Therefore the inner loop will not run because the value of `j` is 5

Comment: Consider using `for` loops instead `for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++)`. It is designed for situations like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please put the "j" inside the first loop and try

```js
let i = 1;
while(i < 5) {
    console.log('Outer: '+i);
    let j = 1;
    while(j < 4) {
        console.log('Inner: '+j);
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you never reset `j` to 1, after running the inner loop.

this will reset j to 1 after running the inner loop, and the while loop will now run every time the outer loop runs.

```js
let i = 1, j = 1;

while (i < 5) {
  console.log('outer', i);
  while (j < 4) {
    console.log('inner', j);
    j++;
  }
  j = 1;
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Should be reset to 1, not 0

Answer (score 1):

Just move the `j` variable inside the first while loop

```
let i = 1
while (i < 5) {
  let j = 1;
  console.log('outer', i);
  while (j < 4) {
    console.log('inner', j);
    j++;
  }
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your not reseting the inner counter var.

```
let i = 1 , j = 1;
while(i < 5){
    console.log("outer : " + i);
    while(j < 4){
        console.log("inner : " + j);
        j++;
    }
    i++;
    j = 1; //reset here inner counter after full cicle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let i = 1;
while (i < 5) {
  console.log('outer', i);
  let j = 1;
  while (j < 4) {
    console.log('inner', j);
    j++;
  }
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.